# Java window not maximising properly on screen with no taskbar using Substance LAF

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, substance

I've just noticed that when I maximise a frame on my second screen - which has no taskbar - then it ends up with approximately the bounds one would expect if the taskbar was there.

I've just noticed this having switched to Windows 7.  Previously in Vista, I had a utility to add a taskbar to both screens, so this may have been an issue there as well if that were not the case.  I'm pretty sure this hasn't been an issue in Linux with a couple of window managers that I've tried...

If I run my program with the default LAF, then the proper behaviour is exhibited (using the full horizontal space of the screen).  I suppose StackOverflow isn't really the best place to file a Substance bug report, but if anyone can suggest a remedy, or confirm that it is indeed a bug and help to identify the circumstances under which it occurs it would be much appreciated.

edit: I've just been digging through the source code a bit and found some references to [issue 213](http://java.net/jira/browse/SUBSTANCE-213); precisely the defect I'm now experiencing, which was supposedly fixed at the time (back in 2007) and reported to be working correctly in XP & Vista with a contemporary build (4.1). I might try to debug the relevant bits of code at some point; looks fairly manageable.

/tumbleweed

Answer (score 1):

I was going to say, if it's only occurring with the Substance LaF, then it definitely sounds like a bug that you should report... but I just saw your edit before posting.  Good luck with persuading them to fix it after 4 years!

In the meantime, the only real workaround you could try is getting the insets of the current display and setting the size that way. Here's some code which works out the resolution, bounds and how much usable space is available on each of your monitors:

```
 public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        GraphicsDevice[] gds = ge.getScreenDevices();
        for (GraphicsDevice gd : gds) {
            GraphicsConfiguration gc = gd.getDefaultConfiguration();
            System.out.println("Bounds = " + gc.getBounds());
            System.out.println("Insets = " + Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenInsets(gc));
        }
    }
```

On a dual-screen Windows setup like I have, this shows the following:

```
Bounds = java.awt.Rectangle[x=0,y=0,width=1280,height=1024] 
Insets = java.awt.Insets[top=0,left=0,bottom=30,right=0] 
Bounds = java.awt.Rectangle[x=1280,y=0,width=1280,height=1024] 
Insets = java.awt.Insets[top=0,left=0,bottom=0,right=0]
```

Notice the 30-pixel insets at the bottom of monitor 1.

Now all you need to do is work out what screen your application is running on.  You can use `Window.getGraphicsConfiguration()` this to get the graphics configuration for the active screen if your application window is a `JFrame` or any other subclass of `Window`.

I hope that helps (and perhaps it will help the people working on the Substance bug!)

Comment: Thanks so much for answering (I was coming to terms with the prospect of 2 tumbleweed badges from 2 questions in a row... lonely feeling!).  I didn't know the proper way to query insets.  As it happens, I have some similar-ish code for making a window fullscreen, and am finding that although the bounds are being set to the proper size of the whole screen, I'm getting the same basic problem. Anyway, I need to go now, but your answer is definitely helpful. Unfortunately Substance isn't as maintained now since the guy is mostly working on Android.

Comment: btw, I'd give you an upvote (not an accept, since it's not really an answer and it looks like I'm going to have to roll up my sleeves and modify substance to fix this)... but I already undid upvoting and now the system won't let me re-instate the upvote unless you edit your answer.

Comment: OK, I made a no-changes edit for you. BTW, I believe this is the best answer you'll get from someone who doesn't have control over the Substance project. Sorry it wasn't the answer you were hoping for. ;)

Comment: well, looking into the substance source, it was clear that the bug had already been addressed at some point (bug 213 was fixed but I guess there was a regression at some point).  As I mentioned in a comment above, I'm already working out which screen I'm on & explicitly setting the bounds to the size of the full screen when I go into my full screen mode... it doesn't work when using Substance though for some reason.

Comment: Oh... Do you mean the values of the Insets you get are incorrect when the LaF is active, or that the window size doesn't get set properly?

Comment: Window size doesn't get set properly.

Comment: alas this bug ( or lack of feature ) is listed on oracle site as of 2011, but is tilll present on any lookAndFeel implenetaiotn - OR on undecorated windows :|